# Best practices for URLs in openid configuration (well-known) for Auth Servers

Tags: security, url, openid-connect, openid, case-sensitive

The URL specification states clearly that parts of the URL can be case-sensitive. So people can clearly use any case as they see fit.

The Well-known endpoint configuration for Open ID Connect is one something that Authorization servers publish (and the values are likely to be cast in stone once published).

Noticed an Identity vendor which had a jwks URI which uses the uppercase JWKS.

This sounded pretty strange - Not only did they choose to use JWKS (in uppercase) they also do not allow that value to be changed!!.

Looked at the well-known Config URI/URL pattern used by the giants ([Google](https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration), [Microsoft](https://login.windows.net/common/.well-known/openid-configuration)) and other Identity leaders (e.g Auth0, Okta) and all of the URIs use lower-case values.

Here is an example from a [local University](https://monashuni.okta.com/.well-known/openid-configuration) that uses Okta. I looked at quite a few examples and I am struggling to find ones that use uppercase for their Open ID well-known config URLs.

Is there a best practice in this space that the leading players adopt/embrace?

Is there documentation available in this space for people to follow?

Found a good resource on URL Design guidelines (generic one however found it to be pretty comprehensive and well thought out)from [Queensland Govt](https://www.forgov.qld.gov.au/url-design-guidelines-principles-all).

This might be a good resource for folks thinking about URLs in their solution

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is lower case, with hyphens for long names - pretty much everyone adopts this, though there are some bad players.

Certain parts of URLs are specified to be case insensitive, so servers should accept any mix of case - though personally I would not rely on it without testing:

- The [scheme](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.1), eg HTtps
- The [domain name](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4343), eg myCOMPANY.com

Other parts of URLs, such as JWKS may or may not be case sensitive - on Windows / MacOS it may not matter - but Linux tends to be strictest.

To summarize, I always make my own URLs or those I can influence case sensitive - in some cases I need to take what I'm given though.